# single and multiple card selection data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Please look at the fiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxmyhzbp/3/)

I have multiple cards in a container. And I have a unique value "objectid".

- I have "selactAll" button, If I click that button, every card should get selected and save button is enable. That time I need to pass all cards in a parameter.
- After "selectAll", if i click on any of the card, that particular card should get unselect. That time if I click save button, the remaining selecteds cards should go in a array format.
- Third one is I can select single card on click inside on button. That time I need to pass the single card in a save parameter. How can I pass these datas in a Array format. Only selected Datas.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.unselectBtn = true;
  $scope.selectBtn = false;
  $scope.saveBtn = true;
  $scope.divs = [1, 2, 3]; // for eample
  $scope.containerSelected = $scope.divs.map(val => false);
  $scope.buttonVisible = $scope.divs.map(val => true);
  $scope.toggleButton = function(e, i) {
  
    console.log('toggleButton')
    $scope.containerSelected[i] = true;
    if($scope.containerSelected[i] = true){
     $scope.saveBtn = false;
    }
    $scope.buttonVisible[i] = false;
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  $scope.toggleContainer = function(i) {
    if ($scope.containerSelected[i]) {
      $scope.containerSelected[i] = false;
      $scope.buttonVisible[i] = true;
    }
  };
  
  $scope.toggleAllButton = function() {
  $scope.unselectBtn = false;
    $scope.selectBtn = true;
    $scope.saveBtn = false;
   $scope.containerSelected = $scope.containerSelected.map(val => true);
    $scope.buttonVisible = $scope.buttonVisible.map(val => false);
    console.log($scope.containerSelected)
  }
  $scope.toggleUnselectAllBtn = function(){
  $scope.unselectBtn = true;
    $scope.selectBtn = false;
    $scope.saveBtn = true;
    $scope.containerSelected = $scope.containerSelected.map(val => true);
    $scope.buttonVisible = $scope.buttonVisible.map(val => false);
    console.log($scope.containerSelected)
  }
  $scope.saveData = function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```css
#myApp {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.container {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10%;
}

button.btn.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.selectedBorder {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#selectALL {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div title="Angular Scope" ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button id="selectALL" ng-hide="selectBtn" ng-click="toggleAllButton()">Select All</button>
  <button id="unselectALL" ng-hide="unselectBtn" ng-click="toggleUnselectAllBtn()">UnSelect All</button>
  <button id="save" ng-hide="saveBtn" ng-click="saveData(div)">Save</button>
  <div id="myApp">


    <div class="container" ng-repeat="div in divs track by $index" ng-class="{ 'selectedBorder': containerSelected[$index] }" ng-click="toggleContainer($index)">
      <button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleButton($event, $index)" ng-show="buttonVisible[$index]">ok</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the position of the value in the `$scope.containerSelected` array corresponds to the ID of the div.

For example, if `$scope.containerSelected` is `[true, false, false]`, then the first div is selected, but the remaining two are not.

With this assumption, you could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to create an array that gives the position of all `true` elements, which would correspond to the div. If the div IDs start at 1, just add 1 to the values in the array.

For example:

```
let dataToSend = $scope.containerSelected.reduce(function(a, e, i) {
    if (e === true)
        a.push(i);
        // or, if they start at 1, use a.push(i+1)
    return a;
}, []);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/pfzg4t1n/